# Show data from database into android table

Tags: java, android

I want to show data from database table into android table, but the data in this activity did not show. The data taken from database is correct, the problem is when i try to set it in table. When activity is open the android table dont show up

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    tools:context=".UserHistory">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="176dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="187dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="93dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="114dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Моята история"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab"
        android:layout_width="375dp"
        android:layout_height="566dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp">

        <TableRow></TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my java logic

```
package com.example.cinemaweb;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class UserHistory extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String ip = "192.168.0.106";
    private String port = "1433";
    private String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    private String db = "AdminToolWeb";
    private String un = "mssqllogin";
    private String password = "mssqllogin$";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_history);

        TextView receiver_msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String str = intent.getStringExtra("IdAccount");
        receiver_msg.setText(str);


        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL = null;
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        try {
            Class.forName(classs);
            ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ":" + port + ";"
                    + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                    + password + ";";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

            ResultSet resultat = statement.executeQuery("select c.Name, Movie_day, Movie_time, TotalPrice, Code from UserHistory a join Movies c on c.ID_DB = a.Movie_id where User_id = " + str);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (resultat.next()) {
                String movieName = resultat.getString(1);
                String Movie_day = resultat.getString(2);
                String Movie_time = resultat.getString(3);
                String TotalPrice = resultat.getString(4);
                String Code = resultat.getString(5);
                sb.append(movieName).append(";").append(Movie_day).append(";").append(Movie_time).append(";").append(TotalPrice).append(";").append(Code).append("_");
            }
            System.out.print(sb.toString());
            System.out.flush();

            String st = new String(sb);

            String[] rows  = st.split("_");
            TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab);
            tableLayout.removeAllViews();


            for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
                String row = rows[i];
                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                final String[] cols = row.split(";");

                Handler handler = null;

                for (int j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {

                    final String col = cols[j];
                    final TextView columsView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    columsView.setText(String.format("%7s", col));
                    tableRow.addView(columsView);
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Do u have any ideas where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the `tableRow` in `tableLayout`, please see the updated for loop to add the rows in tableLayout.

```
      for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
            String row = rows[i];
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            final String[] cols = row.split(";");

            Handler handler = null;

            for (int j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {

                final String col = cols[j];
                final TextView columsView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                columsView.setText(String.format("%7s", col));
                tableRow.addView(columsView);
            }
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow,i);
        }
```